# Printing signbit

Tags: c, bit, sign

I feel like I am nearing an end on this assignment, but do not understand why it only works correctly every other time.                                                                                  If I enter "FFFFFFFF" my program prints out:

0xFFFFFFFF

signBit 1, expBits 255, fractBits 0x007FFFFF

QNaN

but if I enter "FFFFFFFF" again my program prints out:

0xFFFFFFFF

my program will not print out the correct output every time but yet every other time.
Is there anyone who can help me identify where the error occurs in my code?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
// do not change this code except in the following ways:
//   * write code for the following functions:
//      * bigOrSmallEndian()
//      * getNextHexInt()
//      * printLinesForNumber()
//   * change studentName by changing "I. Forgot" to your actual name

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *studentName = "Tenzin Shakya";

// report whether machine is big or small endian
void bigOrSmallEndian()
{
    int num = 1;
    if(*(char *)&num == 1)
    {
      printf("\nbyte order: little-endian\n\n");
   }
   else
  {
      printf("\nbyte order: big-endian\n\n");
  } 
}

// get next int (entered in hex) using scanf()
// returns 1 (success) or 0 (failure)
// if call succeeded, return int value via i pointer
int getNextHexInt(int *i)
{
    // replace this code with the call to scanf()
    //*i = 0;
    //return 1;
    scanf ("%x", i);
    return 1;
} 

// print requested data for the given number
void printNumberData(int i)
{
    //printf("%x %0#10x\n",i,*(int *)&i);
    int tru_exp =0;
    //int stored_exp;
    int negative;
    int exponent;
    int mantissa;

    printf("\n>");
    scanf("%x", &i);
    printf("\n0x%08X",i);

    negative = !!(i & 0x80000000);
    exponent = (i & 0x7f800000) >> 23;
    mantissa = (i & 0x007FFFFF);

    printf("\nsignBit %d, ", negative);
    printf("expbits %d, ", exponent);
    printf("fractbits 0x%08X", mantissa);
    // "%#010x, ", mantissa);

    if(exponent == 0)
    {
        if(mantissa != 0)
        {
            printf("\ndenormalized ");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\nnormalized: ");
        tru_exp = exponent - 127;
    printf("exp = %d", tru_exp);
    }

    if(exponent == 0 && mantissa == 0 && negative == 1)
    {

    printf("\n-zero");

    }

    if(exponent ==0 && mantissa == 0 && negative == 0)
    {
    printf("\n+zero");
    }

    if(exponent == 255 && mantissa != 0 && negative == 1)
    {

    printf("\nQNaN");

    }

    if(exponent == 255 && mantissa != 0 && negative == 0)
    {

    printf("\nSNaN");

    }

    if(exponent == 0xff && mantissa == 0 && negative == 1)
    {
    printf("\n-infinity");
    }

    if(exponent == 0xff && mantissa == 0 && negative == 0)
    {
    printf("\n+infinity");
    }

    printf("\n");
    while(i != 0)
    break;
}

// do not change this function in any way
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     i;                              // number currently being analyzed
    int     nValues;                        // number of values successfully parsed by       scanf

    printf("CS201 - A01p - %s\n\n", studentName);
    bigOrSmallEndian();
    for (;;) {
        if (argc == 1)                      // allow grading script to control ...
            printf("> ");                   // ... whether prompt character is printed
        nValues = getNextHexInt(&i);
        printf("0x%08X\n", i);
        if (! nValues) {                    // encountered bad input
            printf("bad input\n");
            while (getchar() != '\n') ;     // flush bad line from input buffer
            continue;
            }
        printNumberData(i);
        if (i == 0)
            break;
        }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You input the user's number in `getNextHexInt`, yet `printNumberData` asks for the input again with another `scanf`!

Comment: This pretty much solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here's the code for doing that

```
float myFloat;
int myInt;
memcpy(&myInt, &myFloat, 4);
int signBit = ((1 << 31) & myInt) >> 31;
printf("%i\n", signBit)
```

I typed it up in a rush, hopefully it works, ill check it in a sec

Heres a program, but it displays -1 for some reason for sign

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 1337;
    int* b = (int*)&a;

    int signbit = ((1 << 31) & *b) >> 31;
    printf("%i\n", signbit);
    a *= -1;
    signbit = ((1 << 31) & *b) >> 31;
    printf("%i\n", signbit);    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inputting the user's number in `getNextHexInt`, but `printNumberData` asks for the input again with another `scanf`. You don't need the second `scanf` because the input `i` is already set to the user's input from `getNextHexInt`.